# How to get value of last updated row in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to insert the last updated row into a new table using trigger ? How to fetch that row if any of the column (value ) from that table has been updated or changed ?

i am using this code

```
CREATE  TRIGGER `database`.`tbl1_AFTER_UPDATE` 
AFTER UPDATE 
ON `tbl1` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tbl2 (c1,c2,c3) 
   SELECT
   c1,c2,c3 from tbl1;
END
```

But this is inserting all the rows from tbl1 into tbl2, i want only the updated rows to be inserted into tbl2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL extensions to triggers; they are not case sensitive.[Trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  TRIGGER `database`.`tbl1_AFTER_UPDATE` 
AFTER UPDATE 
ON `tbl1` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tbl2 (c1,c2,c3) VALUES (OLD.c1,OLD.c2,OLD.c3);  
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```